# Changes in a copy of the master aspx file not being seen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to make some changes to an asp.net website at short notice.    In order to work on these without affecting the live site I have made a test copy of both the `index.aspx` file and the `Site_Main.Master` file.    I have done this in the past without problems (I think, though I am starting to question myself).

The copies of the files are named `index_test.aspx` and `Site_Main_test.Master` respectively.

In the `index_test.aspx` file I have updated the `MasterPageFile` field accordingly...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="True"
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site_Main_test.Master"
 
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="EWS.L2B.Web.Index"  %>
```

When I visit `index_test.aspx` in the browser it works fine, telling me I have succesfully set up the conditions to work on test versions of the files.

The problem is when I start to make changes in `Site_Main_test.Master` it doesn't seem to be 'seeing' those changes.

So in order to debug this issue, I put a simple `Response.Write("<!-- Test -->");` near the top of the Master file.   No sign of that in the page response when visiting index_test.aspx in the browser.

Scratching my head, I decide to risk putting the same in the original `Site_Main.Master` file, and load the `index.aspx` in the browser.   The `<!-- Test -->` comment shows up!

I am fully aware this is probably an unrecommended way of working on an asp.net website but I don't have time to figure out another way to do this.

I can't figure out why changes to the original Master file are immediately apparent, whereas changes in the test copies seem to be being ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

(As another troubleshooting test I deliberately broke `Site_Main_test.Master`, which does generate an error when I visit `index_test.aspx`,  which tells me it is at least picking up the copy of the Master file)

Comment: change `"index.aspx.cs" ` also

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The codebehind has been compiled so I can't do that without doing a full redeploy using Visual Studio...  I am trying to avoid an extensive redeploy.  I am sure I've done this in the past without having to do that.

Comment: How do you deploy from your source control to here and your test site?, that is the proper way to test perhaps...

Comment: As mentioned I'm trying to do this quickly and lacking the skills to do a full deploy with all the problems that would entail on a live site...  I have been able to do this in the past.  It's working on TWO files versus deploying an entire site consisting of hundreds of files.

Comment: To clarify,  I am not making changes in the codebehind files, so there should be no need to create copies of those.  I am working on the code in plaintext Site_Main.Master